# SolR RPT field type causes not loading core

Tags: solr

I'm using SolR 4.10.2 and tried to get an existing core running with an RPT field.
Therefore, I took following steps

- put JTS in classpath
- added RPT fieldtype definition
- added field with corresponding fieldtype

as a result, the core was not loaded anymore. In the logs there is neither an error nor a warning.

I removed the field definition -> same error
I removed the field type definition -> works

In error state, I get following lines in my log file:

```
719  [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.10.2/test/lib/jts-1.13.jar' to classloader
  [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO  
957 org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'test/rules/'
1017 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.Config  – Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
1022 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – Reading Solr Schema from test/rules/conf/schema.xml
1032 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema  – [rules] Schema name=rules core of the project
```

so everything seems fine up to that step. What I'm missing in comparison to the working state, beneath several additional outputs, is a line like:

```
1053 [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-3] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Creating SolrCore 'rules' using configuration from instancedir test/rules/
```

As said, no error nor warning outputs

Any hints, where to look further?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found it myself.

Though SolR wrote:

```
719  [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/usr/local/Cellar/solr/4.10.2/test/lib/jts-1.13.jar' to classloader
  [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO
```

and no error output, the JTS jar file simply was not used. It has to go to

```
solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

there and only there, it is accepted. No matter if there is stated it was added to classpath and it looks like loaded, as there is NO ClassNotFound.